# Swift 3: Rounding a result embedded in text in a simple calculator

Tags: swift, decimal, rounding, calculator, reset

I am absolutely new to Swift 3, my only experience being some basic HTML and JavaScript back in the days before Microsoft FrontPage, Facebook, etc.

I am trying to make a (relatively) simple calculator that will do some math to calculate how much liquid oxygen I would need for patients.

The two problems I am having are that if someone leaves a field blank, the app will crash.  The second is that I would like the result to go to one decimal place.

I have found answers about blank fields and rounding, but not my exact example, and I simply get errors that I don't know how to fix.

Please keep in mind that the answers to any questions to me that begin with "Why did you do..." are twofold: 1) because I saw an example like that on the web, and 2) I have no idea what I'm doing.

Code is below.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  AECalc
//
//  Created by Marco Metzler on 12/31/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Metzler. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var PTLPM: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var LTVVents: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Vents: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var EmergLPM: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Ground: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Flight: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var LOX: UILabel!



@IBAction func Calculate(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let aText = PTLPM.text
    let bText = LTVVents.text
    let cText = Vents.text
    let dText = EmergLPM.text
    let eText = Ground.text
    let fText = Flight.text
    let a = Float(aText!)
    let b = Float(bText!)
    let c = Float(cText!)
    let d = Float(dText!)
    let e = Float(eText!)
    let f = Float(fText!)
    let PtReq = (a! + d!)
    let LTVTot = (b! * 20)
    let VTot = (c! * 15)
    let VentTot = (LTVTot + VTot)
    let AllOx = ((VentTot + PtReq) * 60)
    let TotTime = (e! + f!)
    let answer = ((AllOx * TotTime) / 804)

    LOX.text = "LOX required: \(answer) liters."

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //The code below hides the keypad when you tap blank space on the screen. I would prefer to have a "done" button on the keypad.

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:))))


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Comment: If a field is blank, what would you like to happen?  What would you like to do if the field doesn't convert to a Float? Use defaults? Print an error?

Comment: This question is way too broad. "The two problems I am having are that if someone leaves a field blank, the app will crash. The second is that I would like the result to go to one decimal place." You're just throwing your whole app at us and saying "Fix this". Pick _one_ problem at a _precise_ point in your code, say what you are doing, what you want to have happen, and what does happen.

Comment: You mentioned that you found answers regarding the blank fields and rounding, but they cause errors.  Can you post those errors so that we can see what you've tried and hasn't worked and guide you from there?

Comment: Hello vacawama.  If the field is left blank, then I would like the app to treat it like a zero.   sorry for being vague...thanks.

Comment: Hello Bek,   I inserted the text provided by nathan below, and formatted it as best I know how:                                                                                  LOX.text = String(format: "%.1f", "LOX required: \(answer) liters.")    The app runs, and gives no errors at all, but it always returns 0.0.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem #1: Blank Field Causes App Crash**

This is because you are force unwrapping optional values with the `!`:

```
let aText = PTLPM.text
let a = Float(aText!)
let PtReq = (a! + d!)
```

This will cause a crash if the text field is empty, or the `String` cannot be converted to a `Float`.

Instead, check to see if the values are `nil` by safely unwrapping them. One way to do this is with some `guard` statements.

```
guard let aText = PTLPM.text else {
    // handle case where text is nil here
}

guard let a = Float(aText) else {
    // handle case where the text is not a valid Float here
}
```

This will ensure that your variables are actual values before proceeding.

**Problem #2: Rounding**

This just requires the usage of the `String` constructor that takes in a format:

```
LOX.text = String(format: "%.1f", answer)
```

Comment: Hello nathan...thanks for the help.   I inserted the code that you provided, and formatted it as best I know how:                                                                                  LOX.text = String(format: "%.1f", "LOX required: \(answer) liters.")             The app runs, and gives no errors at all, but it always returns 0.0 no matter what numbers I put into the fields.  So, the rounding works exactly like I would like (thanks!), but it broke the calculation.  Any ideas?

Comment: The second argument to the string constructor should be a number, not a string. Try this: `LOX.text = String(format: "%.1f", answer)`

Comment: nathan...thanks.  It works.  Would I just have to put in a text label before the answer?  I wanted the result to read, on the screen, "LOX required: 34.5 liters".  Your code works perfectly and returns "34.5".  I have tried to format it to print out the whole statement, but to no avail.  Would you suggest a simple inactive label somewhere on the screen before the calculation result?

Comment: Yeah use a `UILabel` like you have in your original question. Something like `LOX.text = "LOX required: \(String(format: "%.1f", answer)) liters"`

Comment: Worked.  Thanks again!  I just didn't know the correct syntax.

Comment: No problem! If my answer was helpful, feel free to mark it as correct so others in the future can benefit as well. Good luck with your app.